# Lexicon usage, adjectives order

Tags: adjectives

- He was carrying a *nice new black leather* briefcase.
- He was carrying a *nice black new leather* briefcase.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1):

The first is the normal order.

```
Quality.  nice   
Size.     ---   
Age.      new   
Shape.    ---   
Colour.   black   
Material. leather   
Purpose.  ---
```

There are lots of resources on adjective order. But both sentences are somewhat unnatural, as they have too many adjectives. Two adjectives are fine, three are sometimes okay, but four look like something from an English test.  Put some of the descriptive words in a separate phrase.

> He was carrying a nice new briefcase made of black leather.